# Understanding Summation Representations of the Determinant in the Context of Alternating Multilinear Functions

Tags: linear-algebra

Let D be an alternating, n-linear function on $n \times n$ matrices over a commutative ring K with identity, and let A be an $n \times n$ matrix over K with rows $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n $. It is known that each row can be represented as:

$ a_i = \sum_{j=1}^n A(i, j) \epsilon_j $

Given that $ D(A) = D(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n) $, the expression is evaluated in many sources as:

$ 
D(A) = \sum_{k_1=1}^n \sum_{k_2=1}^n \ldots \sum_{k_n=1}^n A(1, k_1) A(2, k_2) \ldots A(n, k_n) D(\epsilon_{k_1}, \epsilon_{k_2}, \ldots, \epsilon_{k_n}) 
$

However, the comprehension of this expression poses a challenge.

**Question 1:**

Is the above expression equivalent to the following?

$
D(A) = \sum_{k_n=1}^n \left( \cdots \left( \sum_{k_2=1}^n \left( \sum_{k_1=1}^n A(1, k_1) A(2, k_2) \cdots A(n, k_n) \cdot D(\epsilon_{k_1}, \epsilon_{k_2}, \ldots, \epsilon_{k_n}) \right) \right) \cdots \right) 
$

**Question 2:**

Why is the expression not represented as below?

$
D(A) = \left[ \left( \sum_{j = k_1}^n A(1, j) \right) \cdots \left( \sum_{j = k_n}^n A(n, j) \right) \right] D(\epsilon_{k_1}, \epsilon_{k_2}, \cdots, \epsilon_{k_n}) 
$

**Question 3:**

If the expression is not equivalent to either of the expressions in Questions 1 and 2, could someone elucidate the full derivation of the expression, providing a step-by-step walkthrough?

Comment: One in question 2 looks sans thing to me but one in question 3 makes no sense. To comprehend that expression I will suggest try it for n = 2 and 3. Write down the entire expression and expand it using multilinearity.

Comment: I am just very confused on what $D(A) = \sum_{k_1=1}^n \sum_{k_2=1}^n \ldots \sum_{k_n=1}^n A(1, k_1) A(2, k_2) \ldots A(n, k_n) D(\epsilon_{k_1}, \epsilon_{k_2}, \ldots, \epsilon_{k_n})$ is. Such that I am not sure whether that expressions to one in Question 1 or Question 2. Question 3 simply puts that if my assumption is wrong and it does not equal to either of them ?